# Transform column data to row data R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have data on the following format:

```
# Reproducible example
order <- c(4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,  4,  5,  6, 7 ,8 ,9 )

values <- c(100,  74 , 70 , 88, 104 ,177  ,88, 189 , 75 , 58, 105, 171 , 29,  60 , 71 , 37 , 93,  99, 206 , 74 , 82 , 69 , 67, 102, 161 , 60 , 92 , 62 ,104, 34, 108,  53 , 50  ,80 , 70 , 77 , 76, 105 ,115 , 78)

journey_id <- c(1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,2, 2, 2 ,2 ,2 ,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ,2, 2, 2 ,2, 3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3)

df <- data.frame(order, values, journey_id)
```

Where `order` refers to a stop along a route, and `values` are observed values of that stop. I would transform this to journey based data, where each row should be an observation of a single journey, where the columns are the `order` and the values are taken from `values`. All journeys do not necessarily have an observed value for all the stops.

The output should look like this:

```
## OUTPUT## 

#         1 ,   2,   3,    4,    5,    6,    7,   8,    9,   10,  ..., 20
#journey1 100,  74,  70,   88,   104,  177,  88,  189,  75,  58,  ..., 93
#journey2 99,   206, 74,   82,   69,   67,   102, 161,  60,  92,  ..., 80
#journey3 70,   77,  76,   105,  115,  78,   NA,  NA,   NA,  NA,  ..., NA
```

My data is quite large, so if possible I'd prefer to not loop over the rows in the data frame, but rather use a vectorized solution.

The value associated with a stop is not in all cases unique for a single journey.

Comment: *All journeys does not necessarily have an observed value for all the stops*. Does this mean that also for `order == 1` sometimes this is not present?

Comment: `order == 1` is always present, `order == 10` could be missing.

Comment: Do you know how I could solve this @GKi ?

Comment: If you want to sum up the values, a possible way might be: `xtabs(Vals ~ journey + Order, cbind(df, journey=cumsum(df$Order == 1)))` but then you have 0 in case of no observation.

Comment: I don't want to sum the values, I just wish to get the value associated with a stop on a journye basis.

Comment: It's sort of what Maël suggested, but with the correction that my observations are not unique; `Order` & `Vals` can be the same for multiple journeys. @GKi

Comment: Can you give an example in the question? (Or maybe ask a new one?)

Comment: OK, I'm not sure how to copy my data frame to here, but will try to reproduce a data frame which yields the same error.

Comment: Maybe something like `df <- data.frame(Order = c(1,2,2,3,1,2,3), Vals=1:7)` ?

Comment: Yes precisely @GKi ! This is the error/warning I encountered which is not what I desired: `"Warning: Values from `Vals` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
"`

Comment: What should be done with the values, in this case `2` and `3` for Journey1 and `Order==2`?

Comment: This means that I have several values for a single stop on a certain journey, correct? I have to investigate why this is the case. I will have to get back to you. I'm sorry I didn't think it would be possible.

Comment: @GKi I have now edited the question as I identified the error in my data cleaning process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "order", values_from = "values")

  journey_id   4   5  6   7   8   9  10  11 12 13  14  15 16  17 18 19 20
1          1 100  74 70  88 104 177  88 189 75 58 105 171 29  60 71 37 93
2          2  99 206 74  82  69  67 102 161 60 92  62 104 34 108 53 50 80
3          3  70  77 76 105 115  78  NA  NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Do you know how to proceed with the same query, but when the values are not uniquely identified? @Maël

Comment: Can you provide an example with expected output of that?

Comment: I have edited the question as I identified an error in my data cleaning process @Maël

Comment: That is if you would like to edit your answer (removing `mutate()`) and I can accept it :)

Comment: @OLGJ Done, removed mutate

Answer (score 0):

A *base* possibility using `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(values ~ journey_id + order, df)
#          order
#journey_id   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
#         1 100  74  70  88 104 177  88 189  75  58 105 171  29  60  71  37  93
#         2  99 206  74  82  69  67 102 161  60  92  62 104  34 108  53  50  80
#         3  70  77  76 105 115  78   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Another using `reshape`:

```
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "journey_id", timevar = "order")
#   journey_id values.4 values.5 values.6 values.7 values.8 values.9 values.10
#1           1      100       74       70       88      104      177        88
#18          2       99      206       74       82       69       67       102
#35          3       70       77       76      105      115       78        NA
#   values.11 values.12 values.13 values.14 values.15 values.16 values.17
#1        189        75        58       105       171        29        60
#18       161        60        92        62       104        34       108
#35        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#   values.18 values.19 values.20
#1         71        37        93
#18        53        50        80
#35        NA        NA        NA
```